# Ok to Have Soffit Vents Next to HVAC Registers?

Tags: hvac, attic, energy-efficiency, venting, soffit

I have a one-story wood frame home with a fully insulated attic, with 4 large vents at the ridge line and numerous perimeter soffit vents, each consisting of 4 large screened holes drilled in the rafter bay blocks. The home has an attic furnace and insulated ducting with ceiling registers located above windows and near doors.  I noticed that most of the soffit vents are located either right next to or directly above the registers.  This seems inefficient from an energy standpoint.  Is there some reason why this was (or should be) done?

Comment: What do you mean by "fully insulated attic"?

Answer (score 0):

There's usually no correlation between soffit vents and interior HVAC components. The former are simply *outside*, in the sense that they're outside the building envelope. They might as well be empty picture frames hanging on nearby trees.

The real question, though, is whether there's somehow a deficit of insulation in those areas due to clearance issues or whatever. You'd have to investigate that yourself. If the walls and ceiling both have full-thickness insulation per your local standards, all good.